# Display the first item in hasMany ember relationship in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I need to display the first item in an hasMany relationship

Basically a thread could have more than 1 author but I need to display only the first one in a particular template

I've the following json

```
{
    threads: [
        {
           id: 1,
           authors: [2,3]
        }
    ],
    authors: [
        {
            id: 2,
            fullname: "foo"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            fullname: "bar"
        }
    ]        
}
```

And the following models

```
App.Thread = DS.Model.extend({
    authors: DS.hasMany('author')
});

App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
    fullname: DS.attr('string')
});
```

now in my template I'm tring to do something like `{{thread.authors[0].fullname}}` but it doesn't work. I've tried also `thread.authors.0.fullname` according to the handlebars syntax but nothing changed.

Thnx in advance for your help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use Ember.Enumerable's [`firstObject`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#property_firstObject):

```
{{thread.firstObject.fullName}}
```

If you are going to use it in a lot of places, its best to define it as a computed property in the model:

```
App.Thread = DS.Model.extend({
  authors: DS.hasMany('author')

  firstAuthor: Ember.computed.alias('authors.firstObject')
});
```

and use it in your templates as:

```
{{firstAuthor.name}}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Just out of curiosity, what if I need the second? Is there a way?

Comment: @Fed03 Its best to keep as much logic as possible (getting 2nd item, getting Nth item, ...) out of templates. To answer your question there is no pre-defined way to get the 2nd item. You will have to define it as a computed property in your controller, and calculate it in there.

Comment: you can do this.get('authors').objectAt(n) in your controller